# Input line size on stdin retrieval

Tags: c, fgets

I'm using `fgets()` function to store a string in a struct with a fixed size.

```
if(fgets(auth_data->user_id, USR_SIZE, stdin) == NULL)
    EXIT_ON_ERROR_("Error on fgets function\n");
fflush(stdin);
```

I know that all the received strings with the size greater of `USR_SIZE -1` are cut. I need to know that the input strings have exactly that size (`USR_SIZE -1` plus `'\0'` character).

For this purpose i can call `strlen` on them to check if a string has length `< USR_SIZE -1`. But how I can check if the original string was cut by `fgets`.
In both this cases i know first that the string is not in the right format.

Furthermore is `fflush(stdin)` really needed in order to clear the input stream?

Answer (score 0):

fgets stores a newline in the buffer as the last character. No newline in the buffer means either EOF (check with feof) or that the string was cut.

Or you can replace all the validation code with a fread() loop, that reads a preset amount of bytes.

It's incorrect to call fflush on an input stream. From GNU libc manual:

> CONFORMING TO
>         C89, C99, POSIX.1-2001, POSIX.1-2008.
>
> ```
>   The  standards  do  not  specify the behavior for input streams.  Most
>   other implementations behave the same as Linux.
> ```

Instead, read until the end of the stream (or just close it).

Comment: A `read` call will never reach the `EOF` without forcing it with CTRL D. What I obtain is that the main process stucks on waiting. There is another way ?

Answer (score 0):

man page of fgets says
DESCRIPTION

```
 The fgets() function reads at most one less than the number of characters
 specified by size from the given stream and stores them in the string
 str.  Reading stops when a newline character is found, at end-of-file or
 error.  The newline, if any, is retained.  If any characters are read and
 there is no error, a `\0' character is appended to end the string.
```

RETURN VALUES

```
 Upon successful completion, fgets() and gets() return a pointer to the
 string.  If end-of-file occurs before any characters are read, they
 return NULL and the buffer contents remain unchanged.  If an error
 occurs, they return NULL and the buffer contents are indeterminate.  **The
 fgets() and gets() functions do not distinguish between end-of-file and
 error, and callers must use feof(3) and ferror(3) to determine which
 occurred.**
```

**It will never get to know if any character is truncated as you are making it read that many characters only from the file**